# Configuration of a webbroker app in Delphi ( api key, db creds etc )

Tags: delphi, webbroker

I'm developing a Delphi Web Broker application and need guidance on securing the configuration files. The configuration file contains sensitive information like database connection strings and API keys. I want to ensure that this information is adequately protected from unauthorized access.

Most of the organisations woulnt have the skill to compile the code for their deployment, so the aim is be as easy to set up as possible..

my head went to a .config file somewhere but is that opening up to an easy security problem, if the config file with DB passwords etc is always in the same place etc..

Any thoughts would be welcomed.

I can find a lot of generic information or things specific to deploying a desktop app, but not webbroker.

Comment: How do you host your app? Apache module, ISAPI module or stand-alone?

Comment: What are *the configuration files*? We have a webservice with a runtime TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge that just reads from INI files, and the sensitive data in it is encrypted.

Comment: @peter wolf - standalone gci, but suspect i will move to isapi eventually.

Comment: @Jan doggen, do you store the ini outside of the web root folders structure?  my head went to a text file somewhere, but wanted to understand if there was a prefered approach..

Comment: @aberbotimue Ours is not GCI or IsAPI but an executable and the ini file is in its directory. You're talking about a different animal it seems.